# Why my "for" loop only gets the last item in html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I already read [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) and [Why am I only getting the last item from javascript for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23551869/why-am-i-only-getting-the-last-item-from-javascript-for-loop)  but still can't figure out, so I post my code to ask for help

```
function Produit(nom, prix){
    this.nom = nom;
    this.prix = prix;
}

// ______________ Objet ____________________

var apple = new Produit("apple", 0.30);
var banana = new Produit("banana", 0.03);
var pear = new Produit("pear", 0.35);
var kiwi = new Produit("kiwi", 0.40);

var produit = [apple,banana,pear,kiwi];


for (var i = 0; i < produit.length; i++) {
    $('.test').html(produit[i].nom);
};
```

html

```
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

The `for` loop only gets the last item name `"kiwi"` in html.
I tested the loop with `console.log` and `alert` and they both get the 4 item names: "apple","banana","pear","kiwi"

Why doesn't this show up in my HTML?

Comment: Your loop writes the same value to all elements matching `.test` each time. All of your iterations are overwriting the text from the previous iteration.

Comment: The divs are all the same target, because they have the same class.
So the loop will write every value to the same spot (in your case
in all the 4 divs).

You have to give any div an ID, or you have to call the div by
their position in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're changing the content of *every single element with a `test` class* on every loop iteration. Example:

```js
$('.test').html('Replaced');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
<div class="test">3</div>
<div class="test">4</div>
```

If you want to change the *nth* `.test` element on every loop iteration, you can use [`.eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/).

```js
var list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var $test = $('.test');
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  $test.eq(i).html(list[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
<div class="test">3</div>
<div class="test">4</div>
```

Comment: It works, great! I saw "eq" before but never imagine that put the "i" inside can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the line in your for loop to this:

```js
$('.test').eq(i).html(produit[i].nom);
```

Comment: It work perfectly! I think the other answers can do it too, but yours is simple and quick, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

When you call `$(".test").html()` you're replacing the contents of *all* the elements with that class. You need to use `.eq()` to specify a particular one.

```
for (var i = 0; i < produit.length; i++) {
    $('.test').eq(i).html(produit[i].nom);
};
```

Another way to do it would be to pass a function to `.html()`. It receives the index of the element, and can use that to index the `produit` array:

```
$('.test').html(function(i) {
    return produit[i].nom;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you'd like to populate your html so that you get

```
<div class="test">apple</div>
<div class="test">banana</div>
<div class="test">pear</div>
<div class="test">kiwi</div>
```

but instead you are getting

```
<div class="test">kiwi</div>
<div class="test">kiwi</div>
<div class="test">kiwi</div>
<div class="test">kiwi</div>
```

Is that correct?

If so, it's because

```
$('.test').html()
```

selects every matching instance. you aren't looping over the divs.

Comment: So, what's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that this statement:

```
$('.test').html(produit[i].nom);
```

sets the HTML for ALL `.test` elements on every iteration of your loop, thus they are all set to the value of `produit[i].nom` on every iteration of your `for` loop so they all end up with the value at the last iteration of your loop.  You aren't iterating over the `.test` elements to set them one at a time.

---

There are many different ways to do this, but I'll suggest an alternative approach that uses [jQuery's .each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over your collection and then assigns the right HTML to each element:

```
var produit = [apple,banana,pear,kiwi];

$(".test").each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).html(produit[index].nom);
});
```

This is also a little more efficient that some other methods because it evaluates the selector `$(".test")` only once and then iterates that one list of elements rather than re-evaluate the selector every time through the loop.

---

jQuery has lots of tricks up its sleeve.  It turns out that the [`.html()` method](http://api.jquery.com/html/) can also take a callback function that will be called separately for each element in the collection.  So, you can also do this:

```
var produit = [apple,banana,pear,kiwi];

$(".test").html(function(index) {
    return produit[index].nom;
});
```

Comment: Seems good, but I took the other answer, still thanks for your help!